# Are P, NP, PSPACE, and NPSPACE complexity classes?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

In Ullman's *Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages and Computation*,
the union theorem (Theorem 12.15) says

> Let ${f_i(n) | i = 1, 2, ...}$ be a recursively enumerable collection of
> recursive functions. Assume each $i$ and $n$,$f_i(n) <f_{i+1}(n)$.
> There exists an $S(n)$ such that
> $$DSPACE(S(n))  = \cup_i DSPACE(f_i(n))$$

i.e. $DSPACE(f_i(n))$'s are complexity classes, so is $\cup_i DSPACE(f_i(n))$, because it can be written as $DSPACE(S(n))$ for some $S(n)$.

I was wondering if the following popular sets are complexity classes?

Can the union theorem apply to them?

$$P := \cup_i DTIME(n^i)$$
$$NP := \cup_i NTIME(n^i)$$,
$$PSACE := \cup_i DSPACE(n^i)$$,
$$NPSPACE := \cup_i NSPACE(n^i)$$

Thanks.